# Why can't I post on server fault?

Tags: discussion, support, serverfault

I'd like to know why I can't post on serverfault.

I have checked my question history and they all have positive karma.

- When will the ban on server fault end?
- Why was I ban for such a long time (years)?

Answer (score 3):

All your *non-deleted* questions have a non-negative score. But deleted questions count towards the question ban too, even doubly if they are deleted *and* have a negative score. For more details, see the FAQ [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232), which also states

> If you're blocked from asking and unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to post *one* new question 6 months after your last question. Your block will still remain once that question is posted, but a single positively-received question could be enough to lift you out of the block.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the good's [@Glorfindel](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/283889/glorfindel)'s [answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9672/256639) that explain the block. I wanted to paste which question you could improve.

Those deleted questions are the one that hit your ability to post's new's one;

They are at -2 each;

[Why can't my android and ios device can't reach my desktop http serverr? [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014596/why-cant-my-android-and-ios-device-cant-reach-my-desktop-http-serverr)
[How to set up samba with an existing OpenLDAP database? [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/935202/how-to-set-up-samba-with-an-existing-openldap-database)
[Little help for configuring my PaaS DNS settings [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/732512/little-help-for-configuring-my-paas-dns-settings)
[Blank page Code 200 on seafile web under apache https with ssl and fastcgi, no LOG [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/630658/blank-page-code-200-on-seafile-web-under-apache-https-with-ssl-and-fastcgi-no-l)

I post a printscreen;

[image]
[image]

To recover the ability to post new questions, as you got a lot of questions deleted at zero score, maybe improving those could help too if you undelete some.